# GridView, SQL and Parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I present to you my issues (And i apologize for my english ...):

I have a GridView containing the data of my database, from two SqlDataSource, one for my simple items and the second for a dropdown list. 
They are:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="source_personnes" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Formation_2014ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Personnes.id_personne, Personnes.nom_personne, Personnes.prenom_personne, Personnes.actif_personne, Personnes.agence_personne,  Organismes.raison_sociale  FROM Personnes INNER JOIN Organismes ON Personnes.agence_personne = Organismes.id_organisme WHERE (Personnes.actif_personne = 1)"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE Personnes SET nom_personne=@nom_personne, prenom_personne=@prenom_personne, agence_personne = @id_organisme WHERE (id_personne = @id_personne) "
        DeleteCommand="UPDATE Personnes SET actif_personne = 0 WHERE (id_personne = @id_personne)">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="actif_personne" Type="Int16" />
        </SelectParameters>

        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name ="id_organisme" ControlId="id_organisme" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The second one :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="source_organisme" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Formation_2014ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Organismes]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

To explain things, I have the following two tables in my database :

**Personnes** ( id_personne(PK), nom_personne, prenom_personne, actif_personne, #agence_personne)

**Organismes** ( id_organisme(PK), raison_sociale, actif_organisme)

agence_personne related to id_organisme.

My goal is by the integrated update function of the GridView, change my entry in the database for the table Personnes.

Thanks to Tuto found on MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms178294%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178294%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I managed to built my dropdown list, however once you get to step 19 to 20 not for me to make a data bindings as explained. So I have a completely independent list.

I now give you the code for my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridModif" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     DataKeyNames="id_personne" DataSourceID="source_personnes" SkinID="dataGrid">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id_personne">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id_personne") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id_personne") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="nom_personne" HeaderText="Nom" SortExpression="nom_personne" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="prenom_personne" HeaderText="Prénom" SortExpression="prenom_personne" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Agence" SortExpression="raison_sociale">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="id_organisme" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="source_organisme" DataTextField="raison_sociale" 
                    DataValueField="id_organisme" AutoPostBack="True">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="id_organisme" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("raison_sociale") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" DeleteText="Désactiver" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My ultimate goal: When I click on my "Edit" button, the selected item in my list is the ID from the table Personne, I would  select an element from the "Organismes" table and  use it in my update parameters to update the "Personnes"  table . 
I posted that on other french forum, but i have no answer, I hope you could help me more !

-- Edit -- 
I've forgot to post my error >< 
-> System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find control 'id_organisme' in ControlParameter 'id_organisme

Thanks a lot,

Krishnak

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you not able to update the `id_organisme` in the `Personnes` table??

Comment: Also try to add `PropertyName="SelectedValue"` like `<asp:ControlParameter Name ="id_organisme" ControlId="id_organisme" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>` in the `UpdateParameter`

Comment: I could change the id_organisme, but directly in the code, and that what i want to do is to select the id, in my list, and get that id for my sql command, actually i had an error :

System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find control 'id_organisme' in ControlParameter 'id_organisme.

There is the view of my GridView :
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/14/1396509094-sample.png

Comment: With the PropertyName="SelectedValue", it doesn't work :/

Comment: Thats right. Only adding the property name is not going to help. My bad. As you are using the GridView the control names would be genereated on the server based on the number for records in the dataset. Let me try out one example.

Comment: If you found what is going wrong, I'd appreciate ! Here i(ve got two tables, in another page, there is four tables ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found !

So on my DropDown List, I'd Bind a selected value :

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Agence" SortExpression="raison_sociale">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="agence_personne" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="source_organisme" DataTextField="raison_sociale" 
                    DataValueField="id_organisme" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("agence_personne") %>' >
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="agence_personne" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("raison_sociale") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And I just remove the Update Parameters in my SqlDataSource. After that, my update works perfectly !

Comment: Thats great! Actually I was not able to post the code due to some security reasons. But good to know you got it working. You can mark your own answer as "Answer".

Comment: I can't for the moment, in 18 hours :p